# pagination of php glob page

Tags: php, pagination, glob

i have a page that uses glob to display images that is inside a folder. The thing is, i want to display only 20 pics per page. The tutorials about pagination that i found online is related with database, but i did not use database inside my code.

```
$files = glob("uploaded_files/*.*");
usort($files, function ($a, $b) {
return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);
});

foreach ($files as $file) {
echo "<img src='$file' style='height:180px;width:180px; border:2px solid black;  margin:20px 0px 10px  10px; *margin:10px 0px 10px 20px;'>";
}
```

this is my code. how can i make it so that it displays 20 images per page and auto paginate? tq

Comment: what is that resource url which you are seeing?

Comment: the uploaded_files directory is where the images are located

Comment: What is the tutorial about pagination url which you are referring .......

Comment: one of it is http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = glob("uploaded_files/*.*");
usort($files, function ($a, $b) {
return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);
});

$record_count  = 20;
$totla_pages   = ceil(count($files)/$record_count);
$page          = $_REQUEST['page']; ///make it dyanamic :: page num
$offset        = ($page-1)*$record_count;
$files_filter  = array_slice($files, $offset,$record_count);

foreach ($files_filter as $file) {
echo "<img src='$file' style='height:180px;width:180px; border:2px solid black;  margin:20px 0px 10px  10px; *margin:10px 0px 10px 20px;'>";
}

if($totla_pages > 1){
   if($page != 1){
      echo '<a href="thispage.php?page='.($page-1).'">Prev</a>';
   }
   if($page != $totla_pages){
      echo '<a href="thispage.php?page='.($page+1).'">Next</a>';
   }
}
```

But here the problem is that every time $files load all the files then it filters.

Added a simple pagination.

Comment: it only show 20 pics but how to make it go to the next batch of 20 pics? like pic no 21,22,etc ?

Comment: change to `$page          = 2;`

Comment: Please check the code  added a simple pagination. Change `href="thispage.php` to your php page name

Answer (score 0):

This is code that i used for same purpose.

```
/****************************************************
To fetch total number of images for pagination
*****************************************************/


$folder_name=$row[page_addlink] ;
$dirname = "gallery/".$folder_name ; 
$files = glob($dirname."/*.{jpg,gif,png,tiff,jpeg,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);       
$no_of_files=count($files); 


/****************************************************
This is to get total number of records for pagination
*****************************************************/
$rows = $no_of_files;                     
$pagenum=$_GET[pagenum];
/*******************************************
By default page number is 1 
*******************************************/
if (!(isset($pagenum)))
{
$pagenum = 1;
} 
/****************************************************
No of rows to be visibles.Value is set in config file
*****************************************************/                   
$page_rows = $no_of_images_pagination ;    /// defined in connection.php file
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 

if ($pagenum <= 1)
{
$pagenum = 1;
}
elseif ($pagenum > $last)
{
$pagenum = $last;
}               
?>
<div class="right_panel">
<div class="inner">                
<div class="inner_bg">

</br>

<div align='center'>
<?php



if($rows <=$page_rows)
{

}
else
{

if($pagenum!=1)
{
echo "<a href='[URL of your page]?id=$folder_id&pagenum=1' style='text-decoration:none'> <<-First</a> ";
}

$previous = $pagenum-1;
if($pagenum!=1)
{
       echo " <a href='[URL of your page]?id=$folder_id&pagenum=$previous' style='text-decoration:none'><-Previous</a> ";
}                   
//just a spacer
for($k=1;$k<=$last;$k++)
{       
echo " <a href='[URL of your page]?id=$folder_id&pagenum=$k' style='text-decoration:none'>";
if($k==$pagenum)
      {
          echo "<b><u>".$k."</u></b>" ;
      }


   else
     {
         echo $k ;
     }
echo "</a>&nbsp;";

}   

$next = $pagenum+1;
if($pagenum!=$last)
{
echo "<a href='[URL of your page]?id=$folder_id&pagenum=$next' style='text-decoration:none'>Next -></a> ";
}

echo " ";

if($pagenum!=$last)
{
echo " <a href='[URL of your page]?id=$folder_id&pagenum=$last' style='text-decoration:none'>Last ->></a> ";
}

}
?>
</div>
```

You can use this code after little bit modification according to your CSS and page url and directory location.It Works perfectly fine.Good luck